# Is simple harmonic potential only example which is invariant under gauge transform (in SUSY/QM context)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, gauge-theory, scattering, supersymmetry

I'm junior student in physics major, and i didn't study QFT or other graduate course yet, just undergraduated QM. Recently I take brief explanation class about SUSY, and in the class I heard that simple harmonic oscillation (SHO) is important because it is unique potential which is invariant under some gauge transform therefore it doesn't change some kinds of scattering properties (reflection coefficient, etc).

1. Is SHO only example which is invariant under the gauge transform  in SUSY QM?
2. In the description, what kind of gauge transform is meant?
3. How does the gauge transform relate to SUSY?

Comment: Hello anonymoususer and welcome to Physics SE. Could you please expand the acronyms that you use as not all users may be familiar with all of them?

Comment: @ZaellixA Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple theories which are invariant to various kinds of gauge transforms, the simplest gauge transform is simply the SU(1) transformation of a field like
$$A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A_\mu(x) - \partial_\mu f(x)$$
with $f(x)$ an arbitrary funcion, something is said to be gauge invariant if it
doesn't change upon this transformation, an example (other than just a simple harmonic oscillator) is
$$F_{\mu\nu} := \partial_\nu A_\mu - \partial_\mu A_\nu$$
for the photon field which stays the same under this transformation. In SUSY (SUperSYmmetry) we want the field theory to not only abide by this gauge invariance but also SU(2),SU(3) and further extension of the Poincaré group (which is a bit too involved to expaund here)